# How do i release allocated memory for array?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, swift3

I am not understanding how to give weak refrence to the array or release allocated memory of array, can anyone tell me how to fix this leak?

```
 var menuDetails:[[String:Any]] = []//this my global array object
```

Getting following leak even i am using ARC.

Screenshot for array memory leak!

[image: Screen Shot]

I was just scared about that memory leak,can anyone tell how do i fix it?

Comment: what is the size of array@sharayu

Comment: don't know its dynamic.

Comment: is this array have large amount of data@sharayu

Comment: not too much like normal data... having bunch of dictionaries

Comment: There are informative answers here, but a 3 byte leak may (a) not even be a leak and (b) may easily be a bug in Swift. Swift has numerous known leaks. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3399?jql=status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22)%20AND%20text%20~%20%22leak%22 Even in ObjC, we always dealt with the fact that Foundation has known leaks. It may not be possible to get "no leaks" out of the analysis tools. 3 bytes is generally not something you would spend a lot of time on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use a weak reference. If you do that your array will get released immediately.

weak var weakArray: [[String:Any]]? = []

Will contain nil as soon as you create it.

Instead, you should set the array to nil (or empty) once you're done with the contents:

You could use `menuDetails.removeAll() to delete all the entries in the array, or you could change your declaration to make it an Optional

```
var menuDetails:[[String:Any]]? = []//this my global array object
```

And then set it to nil when you're done with it:

```
menuDetails = nil
```

Comment: that is what i was looking for ... easy stuff

Answer (score 0):

An object will only be retained if another object has a strong reference to it. As soon as your view controller disappears, it will most likely be deallocated as well, which automatically removes its strong references to other objects. Thus, if imageArray is strongly referenced only by your disappearing view controller, the memory will automatically be released. You do not need to use an autoreleasepool.

Answer (score 0):

In order to store weak references in arrays and/or dictionaries, you need an intermediate structure.

for example:

```
struct WeakRef 
{ 
  weak var object:AnyObject?
  init( _ objectRef:AnyObject?)
  { object = objectRef }
}

// use WeakRef when you add object instances to your dictionary (or array)

menuDetails[0]["objectKey"] = WeakRef(yourObject)

// you will need additional code to get the actual object out of the intermediate structure
// and given that it is a weak reference you'll also need to deal with its optionality.

if let yourObject = (menuDetails[0]["objectKey"] as? WeakRef)?.object as? YourClass,
{
   // ... do your thing with your object ...

}
```

The syntax could probably be made more legible by wrapping this in custom operators and generics but this is the general approach to it.